# Creating an igraph attribute overview

Tags: r, igraph

I'd like to know if there is a possibility to get a data frame from an igraph element which includes all vertex attributes as colnames.
This looks like a trivial thing to do but I was not able to get it to work so far.
All I could do is

```
cbind(V(igraphE)$attr_1, V(igraphE)$attr_2, V(igraphE)$attr_3, V(igraphE)$attr_4)
```

And of course I have access to all attribute names via

```
 list.vertex.attributes(igraphE)
```

there has to be another way to accomplish this - maybe someone of you knows how to do it.

EDIT: Example

```
test_fun <- function(color1,color2,len){
  vec <- replicate(len,sample(c(color1,color2,NA),1))
  return(vec)
}

set.seed(50)
num_nodes<- 20
test_graph <- erdos.renyi.game(num_nodes, 1/6)
V(test_graph)$color_1 <- test_fun("darkgreen","blue",num_nodes)
V(test_graph)$color_2 <- test_fun("brown","blueviolet",num_nodes)
V(test_graph)$color_3 <- test_fun("red","green",num_nodes)
V(test_graph)$color_4 <- test_fun("red","green",num_nodes)
plot(test_graph, vertex.size=7)
```

Expected result:
 data.frame including all vertex attributes, attributes as colnames

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To whom it may concern - I just found the answer myself. It indeed is really simple and streightforward:

```
df <- as.data.frame(vertex.attributes(test_graph))
```